# Two Server Sharepoint Farm Topology

Tags: sql-server, server-farm, domain, topology

I'm working on creating a product for Sharepoint and have set up a server farm consisting of two machines running Server 2008 R2.

I want to set up SQL2008 on one Machine, and SharePoint 2010 on the other.

The big issue is the Domain Controller. I need to be able to extensively test against SPUsers with names, emails etc. From what I understand, those are Active Directory Accounts only, so I need to set up a domain.

Miscrosoft recommends strongly against having either SQL of SP2010 on the same machine as a domain controller.

Is it smarter in this situation to have one server act SOLELY as a domain controller, and the other act as a single machine SharePoint installation? This machine will be web facing for demos, but shouldn't be subjust to high levels of traffic.

Comment: Do you have a high configuration single system ? If thats true you can go for VM based farm topology as well using Hyper-V. Let us know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install SP2010 on DC but it is not recommended. If you don't have possibility to add more servers then you can go with the following architecture:

- SharePoint Server 2010 and Applications on one server.
- Domain controller and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 running on another

You can even deploy SharePoint Server 2010/SQL Server in a single server farm environment but that must be serving/hosting only a few sites for a limited number of users.

Comment: I've read installing SQL on a domain controller is a bad idea as well. Best reference I have is: http://briankgough.wordpress.com/2009/07/16/sharepoint-on-a-domain-controller/

Comment: Installing SP2010 on DC is even worse. As I said, your only option could be to have DC on a separate server and deploy SharePoint Server 2010/SQL Server in a single server farm environment.